# Restrict text to box without linebreak

Tags: boxes

This:

```
\fbox{\makebox[3cm][l]{long text long text long text long text}}
```

results into this:

[image: \fbox with too long text]

I want it to stop right at the end of the box. No line-wrapping. So the text, which is 'too much', cannot be seen.

Comment: Do you want to break at a char boundary or potentially to have a partial char appearing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fit,breakall]{truncate}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\truncate[]{3cm}{long text long text long text long text}}
\end{document}
```

Read the document to understand the options.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses as much text as will fit in the stated length; the *-form frames only the text that fits, the normal form uses the stated length anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\restrict}{smm}{% #2 is a length, #3 is the text
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=#2\relax\raggedright#3\par
    \setbox2=\lastbox\unskip\unpenalty
    \loop
      \setbox4=\box2
      \setbox2=\lastbox\unskip\unpenalty
    \unless\ifvoid2
    \repeat
    \global\setbox1=\box4
  }% end of the \vbox
  \fbox{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\unhbox}{\box}1}%
}

\begin{document}

\restrict{3cm}{A long text that should be cut at 3cm at most}

\restrict*{3cm}{A long text that should be cut at 3cm at most}

\restrict{3cm}{A long text that is cut at 3cm at most}

\restrict*{3cm}{A long text that is cut at 3cm at most}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to compose a paragraph with the stated length as line width, then dismantle the resulting box until getting at the first line that's finally typeset.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My solution is a similar like egreg's but the `\loop` isn't needed because we have only two lines of the internal praragraph. The lines are set by `\parshape`. First line has given width and second line (if exists) has `\maxdimen` width.

```
\def\restrict#1#2{\setbox0=\vbox{\parshape 2 0pt #1 0pt \maxdimen
   \rightskip=0pt plus1fil\noindent#2\par
   \setbox0=\lastbox \unskip\unpenalty \global\setbox2=\lastbox}%
   \ifvoid2 #2\else \leavevmode\unhbox2 \unskip \fi
}
test: \restrict{3cm}{A long text that should be cut at 3cm at most}
```

The frame around restricted text isn't printed here explicitly. You can do it by another tools.

Comment: Nice idea. It should be `\global\setbox1`, because even numbered scratch register should be used only for local assignments.